# How to Access the Undeletable directory/file in windows operating system?

Tags: windows, cacls, undelete

I have doubt in **directory undeletable** concept. In **Windows operation system**, we *convert a Undeletable file or folder in to deletable* by using the command as **"cacls FolderName /e /c /g %username%:f"**. I used the same command to access the **"Undeletable folders" *(for example Recovery, Documents and Settings etc.,),*** which is present in the **C: drive**. It doesn't work. How they create this kind of folders. If any other ways to do this. Kindly clear me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those folders have the "list folder/read data" permission set to deny for everyone.  Deny takes precedence over allow, so it doesn't matter what permissions you give to a user: the deny setting will overrule it.  You have to remove that setting first, which probably means you also have to take ownership first.  They're owned by SYSTEM.

Comment: so, We are having access permission only not a read/write/modify permissions.

Comment: To delete a folder you first have to delete its contents, and to do that you have to list its contents.  The permission settings prohibit you from doing that, so you can't delete the folder until the deny setting is removed.

Comment: if any possibilities to deny the setting

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  If you want to remove the deny setting you're going to need to use icacls rather than cacls.  Cacls is deprecated and you really shouldn't be using it.  An even better alternative is SetACL, which can be downloaded from http://helgeklein.com/.